# how to check system config, that helps to buy new HDD

Tags: hard-drive, sata

My laptop is 4-5yrs old with Core2Duo CPU. HDD is heating lot so probably going to brick. so which configuration i should check that will help me to know "Which HDD's are compatible with my laptop". SSD are also preferred if they are compatible.

> currunt hdd model is WDC WD3200BEVT-22ZCT0 (11.01A11)

- how to know HDD type ?
- how to know SATA version along BUS speed supported ?

Comment: Heat != failed HD. Cleaned/vacuumed the laptop lately?

Comment: @Xen2050 Yeah... I did that properly .. Even from repairing shop. It goes 27 to 58 degree Celsius in less than hour . and laptop starts to lag. So i think

Comment: Could try taking out the HD and running Ubuntu live from a cd/usb a few hours & see how the computer temp is to make sure. And no better way to see what HD size/plugs for a replacement than to look at the old one

Comment: @Xen2050  oh.. Sure I'll do that. Processor temp stays normal 37-42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know the HDD Model, Serial number and much more

```
sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

May be you have old IDE drive check with

```
sudo hdparm -i /dev/hda
sudo hdparm -I /dev/hda
```

This will show you every information about your disk and storage

```
lshw -class disk -class storage
```

If you have a SATA disk this command will give your the output

```
sudo dmesg | grep SATA
```